# Ubuntu is showing a Black Screen after booting up

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, automount

Yesterday, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my PC along with Windows 10. It was working fine but I wanted to mount my NTFS partitions. So, I created a mount folder at /home/Win and tried to mount one of my NTFS partitions into that folder. After that, when I restarted the OS, it was stuck at the "The login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged in to the computer" with a full black screen in the background. I tried to put my password as well, but no luck with that too.

what could be the problem? Please help, as I am quite new to this OS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mount things to `/home`.

I suggest that you reboot your computer and from the advanced options in GRUB, boot to a root shell prompt (with networking).

At the root shell prompt, run `nano /etc/fstab` and remove or comment out your mount point and reboot with the `reboot` command.